# What happen to counter variable when a for loop ends in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I have to implement an algorithm that can handle the main memory while executing and I was wondering what does happen to a variable that is declared like this (I refer to `int i`):

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    .....
}
```

at the end of the for statement is it kept in memory or is "freed" in some way?

Comment: It goes out of scope.

Comment: Both; it *may* still be in memory, but the compiler shouldn't let your code access that memory using that name (as @stark says, it is out of scope).

Comment: [A really quick explanation of stack frames and frame pointers](https://people.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/419/notes/frames.html)

Comment: @stark: Nothing can go out of scope “while executing.” Lifetime is the issue, not scope. Scope is **where** in program source code an identifier is visible, relative to a particular declaration. Lifetime is **when** during program execution memory is reserved for an object. It is possible for code outside of the scope of a variable’s identifier to access the variable’s object during the object’s lifetime.

Comment: You could say it is ''freed' in some way". It's lifetime ends right after the for loop and the memory where it was stored can be reused from the moment it's lifetime ends.

Comment: @Jabberwocky you gave me the answer I was searching for, thank you. Now I edited the question to add another doubt

Comment: "at the end of the for statement is it kept in memory or is "freed" in some way?" With only the C standard in hand we can't tell. The C standard doesn't describe such things but leaves it entirely up to the implementation. In other words, it depends on the specific system used. On most systems it will stay in memory. On the other hand that memory location may also be used by another variable depending on code/compiler/system/etc.... All the C standard tells us is that we can't access the memory using `i` after the loop.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, no the question is not about reusing the variable with the same name

Answer (score 4):

For a variable declared inside a `for` statement, its lifetime ends when execution of the `for` statement ends. *Lifetime* is the portion of program execution during which memory is reserved for the object in the C model of computing.

When implementing that model, a compiler theoretically can allocate space for the `i` you show on the stack (by adjusting the top-of-stack pointer) when the `for` statement starts and can release that space by a reverse adjustment when the statement ends. In practice, most ordinary compilers plan execution of a whole function and set up one stack frame when the function is started and tear down that stack frame frame when the function ends (with some exceptions, such as for variable length arrays). Within the function, the memory of that stack frame is shared for various purposes according to the compiler’s design.

This means that, when execution of the `for` loop ends, there is probably no immediate adjustment to the stack pointer. However, the memory for the `i` variable might or not be reused for other purposes immediately, depending on what other computations the function is doing and how the compiler arranged things.

This is presuming memory was used for `i` at all. While variables use memory in the computing model the C standard uses, compilers are allowed to generate any code that gets the same observable behavior. (For simple programs, observable behavior is mostly the input and output of a program.) The compiler might use a processor register for `i` and never keep its value in memory. Immediately after execution of the loop ends, the processor can reuse that register for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you define your variable.

If you define it before the loop, and just initialize it inside the loop - it will continue to exist after the loop, preserving the value, modified by the last iteration of the loop. Like:

```
int i;//define variable here

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //some code inside the loop
}

printf("Value of i is: %i", i);//print variable here
```

Output will be:

```
Value of i is: 10
```

In the other case - you can both define and initialize the variable inside the loop (as you did in your example). In this case the variable is being deleted, right after the program leaves the loop, since it leaves a local scope. You can try to pass it to a function, after the loop - you will receive compile error.

Comment: That does not really answer the question because the OP's code is `for(int i=0;...`.

Comment: Take a look on the last text paragraph. :)